# how to create a table from an excel sheet?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there an easy tutorial?

I'd like to create a table that exactly matches the excel table, is it possible to do something like "create table from excel sheet"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the Import and Export Wizard if you're only importing a small number of sheets.

In SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the database name, then Tasks -> Import Data. Then follow the wizard.

Comment: exactly what i was going to day